# QScrollArea - auto scroll

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

Trato de hacer que al momento de añadir un nuevo objeto al `QSCrollArea` una vez que se llene su campo visible automáticamente baje para mostrar el nuevo elemento añadido:

ya que actualmente solamente muestra 10 widget por ejemplo y si se afrega uno mas no lo muestra devido a que el slider no baja para mostrar la posision 11 y se mantiene al principio del QScrollArea

anexo un codigo de ejemplo:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication,QLabel,QWidget,QScrollArea,QVBoxLayout,QHBoxLayout

class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.widget = QWidget(self)
        self.scrollArea = QScrollArea()
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self.widget)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.widget)
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)

        for i in range(100):
            self.w = QWidget(self)
            self.layout2 = QHBoxLayout(self.w)
            self.label = QLabel("loop")
            self.layout2.addWidget(self.label)
            self.layout.addWidget(self.w)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.scrollArea)



app = QApplication([])
m = Main()
m.resize(800,600)
m.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo más simple para realizar automáticamente el scroll necesario para visualizar un determinado widget es usar el método [`QScrollArea.ensureWidgetVisible`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscrollarea.html#ensureWidgetVisible).

```
self.scrollArea.ensureWidgetVisible(self.label)
```

Otra opción para ir al final del área sería obtener el máximo del slider con `QAbstractSlider.maximum()` de la barra vertical  y realizar el scroll mediante `QAbstractSlider.setValue`.

```
self._vbar = self.scrollArea.verticalScrollBar()
self.vbar.setValue(self._vbar.maximum())
```

El problema es que no es tan fácil, simplemente por razones de índole temporal.

Primero, si creas los widgets en el inicializador como haces ahora, no puedes realizar el scroll en ese momento porque el `ScrollArea` (y todo lo demás) tiene un tamaño de 0, nada se ha dibujado todavía (solo se calcula el tamaño y se actualizan los widgets cuando llega el momento de mostrarlos). Puedes delegar la creación de los widgets para después de la inicialización, o bien postergar el scroll automático solo, haciendo algo así:

```
def __init__():
    ...
    ...
    ...

    for i in range(100):
        label = QLabel("loop")
        self.layout.addWidget(label)

    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, functools.partial(self.scrollArea.ensureWidgetVisible, self.label))
```

Aunque se creen los widgets fuera del inicializador, sigue existiendo un problema, no puedes utilizar ninguno de los dos métodos mencionados al principio **justo después de crear y agregar el widget** al layout de tu scrollarea. Esto se debe a que en ese momento el widget aún no se ha actualizado, ni su tamaño recalculado. Añadir un widget al layout desencadena una serie de eventos entre el layout, el widget contenedor la ScrollArea, los sliders... que han de ser procesados.

Podemos lidiar con ello de varias formas, una de ellas podría ser usar la señal `rangeChanged` de la barra vertical y moverla hasta abajo cuando proceda, por ejemplo:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea()
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.widget)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.widget)
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.scrollArea)
        self._vbar = self.scrollArea.verticalScrollBar()  
        self._vbar.rangeChanged.connect(self.scroll_to_end)
        self._scroll_items = 0

        for i in range(100):
            w = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
            layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(w)
            label = QtWidgets.QLabel(f"loop {i}")
            layout.addWidget(label)
            self.layout.addWidget(label)
            self.label = label

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def scroll_to_end(self):
        items = self.layout.count()
        if self._scroll_items < items:
            self._vbar.setValue(self._vbar.maximum())
        self._scroll_items = items


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    m = Main()
    m.resize(800, 600)
    m.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Otra posibilidad es recurrir de nuevo a `QtCore.QTimer.singleShot` para dar tiempo a que se procesen los eventos necesarios y la ScrollArea se actualice:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

import functools
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets



class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(800, 600)
        self.central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
        self.central_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.central_widget)

        self.area_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea()
        self.area_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.area_widget)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.area_widget)
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)


        btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Agregar")
        btn.clicked.connect(self.add_row)
        self.central_layout.addWidget(self.scrollArea)
        self.central_layout.addWidget(btn)


    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def add_row(self):
        label = QtWidgets.QLabel(f"Loop")
        self.area_layout.addWidget(label)
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(1, functools.partial(self.scrollArea.ensureWidgetVisible, label))



if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Main()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

El problema de esta aproximación es que podemos quedarnos cortos o largos en nuestra estimación del tiempo necesario, no es determinista.

Answer (score 1):

Agrego la solución a la que llegué para el mismo problema por si le sirve a otros. Es una combinación de lo ya expuesto agregando el uso de hilos.

Desde el hilo ppal del programa creamos los objetos dentro del scrollArea. Luego se llama a un hilo a parte para que realice la espera con un time.sleep() que en mi caso con un valor de tan sólo 0.01 fue lo suficientemente corto para que a vista del usuario no detecte el evento pero lo suficientemente largo para que ya estén todos los elementos cargados, y eso que en mi caso son objetos complejos que están compuestos por varios labels y botones.

**NOTA:** Los objetos deben crearse desde el hilo del programa porque un hilo nuevo no tiene acceso al parent ni pasándolo por parámetro, les dará error si crean un hilo nuevo para llamar a la función que crea el objeto.
También quería agregar que el motivo por el cuál esto funciona, es porque al llamar a otro hilo a que realice el ajuste del valor del scroll, no interviene en el hilo principal dejando que termine con normalidad (y eso incluye la redimensión y aparición de los objetos en pantalla), y eso sucede antes del tiempo que le damos de 0.01 seg.

Editando el código de la consulta quedaría así:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication,QLabel,QWidget,QScrollArea,QVBoxLayout,QHBoxLayout
import threading
import time

class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.widget = QWidget(self)
        self.scrollArea = QScrollArea()
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self.widget)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.widget)
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)

        for i in range(100):
            self.w = QWidget(self)
            self.layout2 = QHBoxLayout(self.w)
            self.label = QLabel("loop")
            self.layout2.addWidget(self.label)
            self.layout.addWidget(self.w)
            threading.Thread(target=self.mostrar_ultimo, args=(self.label,)).start()

        self.setCentralWidget(self.scrollArea)

    def mostrar_ultimo(self, obj):
        time.sleep(0.01)
        self.scrollArea.ensureWidgetVisible(obj)

app = QApplication([])
m = Main()
m.resize(800,600)
m.show()
app.exec_()
```