# ¿Porqué no puedo crear objetos en tiempo de ejecución?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Preparé un código para que puedan ver el problema, donde tengo una función que crea un objeto (***renglon***) desde una clase propia(***Lista_Venta***). Cuando ejecuto dicha función desde el ***init*** de la ventana principal, los objetos se crean sin problema, pero cuando llamo a la misma función desde un botón, los objetos se crean pero no se muestran.
Leí por ahí que la causa podría ser que el objeto que creo no tenga las propiedades de tamaño etc, pero en la misma clase se configura todo como yo necesito, así que no le falta nada.
**Nota**: No muestro la ventana porque no es más un MainWindow con un QPushButton.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QFrame

from pruebas.mw_ppal import *
from renglones import *

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.crea_renglon()
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.crea_renglon)

        self.show()
    
    def crea_renglon(self):
        renglon = Lista_venta(["Nro", "Concepto", "Pcio", "Cant", "Subtotal"], "1", 660, 0, self.ui.centralwidget)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt establece las siguientes reglas:

- Cuando se muestra un widget entonces se mostraran sus hijos presentes en ese momento. Si se añade un nuevo widget este no será visible hasta que uses su propio metodo show, asi que la solución es añadir `renglon.show()`.
- Los layouts ademas de manejar la geometria de los widgets y establecer el parentezco tambien hace visible al widget llamando internamente al metodo show por eso funciona.

Comment: La verdad que muchas gracias, esa simple línea de código me evita cambiar muchas otras líneas y mantener mi proyecto original.

Answer (score 0):

He resuelto mi problema pero tuve que usar otro método distinto ya que no encuentro respuestas a éste problema. Puede que mi solución no les sirva a otros pero quizás sí ésta información.

El problema básicamente es que en tiempo de ejecución sólo he podido encontrar el método de **addWidget** para ser aplicado sobre algún **Layout**. Es la única manera que encontré de agregar widgets y que sean visibles. Me obliga a usar un **Layout** que lo estaba evitando porque no podía hacer que se comporte como necesitaba, pero en combinación con un ScrollArea y una solución que encontré en otra publicación pude solucionar mi problema, si alguno le interesa paso link ([QScrollArea - auto scroll](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/264030/qscrollarea-auto-scroll/480601#480601))

Entonces, tengan en cuenta que si agregan un widget desde el `__init__()` no hay problema, pero en tiempo de ejecución deberán utilizar Layout (ej: `self.layout.addWidget(self.label)`) y de ser necesario combinarlos con otros widgets para que se comporten como ustedes deseen.

Comment: Mira mi respuesta ya que te dá más detalle del problema y además explica porque tu nueva solución funciona.